# Having trouble JSON encoded data from MySQL through Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have been trying to parse my data from my php file to reflect the data in the array using this area graph example found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic). Before, I had all the data commented out to going to the array, but now I am just trying to display one part of data. I don't know if it has to do with the data being parsed or I am not calling the data correctly into the HTML file. The variable 'js_array' was not there before, but I thought it could be a solution to my problem, but unfortunately it still comes out with a blank page.

PHP code:

```
<?php
// A simple PHP script demonstrating how to connect to MySQL.
// Press the 'Run' button on the top to start the web server,
// then click the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console.

$servername = getenv('IP');
$username = getenv('C9_USER');
$password = "";
$database = "reports2";
$dbport = 3306;

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully (".$db->host_info.")";

$query = "SELECT wTCP_UP1

          FROM 1_sp12_la UNION ALL SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_rs UNION           SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_sf";        

  //1_sp12_la._Provider, 1_sp12_la.NORMALIZED_LAT,      1_sp12_la.NORMALIZED_LONG, 1_sp12_la.wTCP_UP1, 1_sp12_la._wTCP_DOWN2

   // 1_sp12_rs._Provider, 1_sp12_rs.NORMALIZED_LONG, 1_sp12_rs.NORMALIZED_LAT, 1_sp12_rs.wTCP_UP1, 1_sp12_rs._wTCP_DOWN2

 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

 $data = array();



//$stmt->execute();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $data[] = $row; 

    // echo " ID: " . $row["att_fall2012_id"] . ", Normalized Latitude: " .    $row["NORMALIZED_LAT"] . 
     //", Location ID: " .  $row["_Location_ID"] . ", Provider: " . $row["_Provider"] . ", TCP Upload Speed:" 
      //. $row["wTCP_UP1"] . ", TCP Download Speed:"  . $row["_wTCP_DOWN1"] .nl2br ("\n") ;

    //echo nl2br("\n");

}


 echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


//$json_data = json_encode($data);
//file_put_contents('CityData/attfall2012.json', $json_data);
  ?>
```

and here my HTML file where the graph is supposed to be.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Area Example</title>

 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">   </div>

<script type = "text/javascript">  
 js_array = new Array( <?php echo implode(',' , $data);  ?>);

 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
            'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {

            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>  <br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{

        data: js_array

    }]
});
});
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>


 <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0    auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched all over the place, but nothing. I am also not the greatest with javascript and very new to Highcharts. Thanks! Please let me know if you need more info.

**Edit:** Here is the JSON output:

```
[{"wTCP_UP1":6163},{"wTCP_UP1":13622},{"wTCP_UP1":456.1},{"wTCP_UP1":2142.3},{"wTCP_UP1":6317},{"wTCP_UP1":1710},{"wTCP_UP1":7966},{"wTCP_UP1":2680},{"wTCP_UP1":1157},{"wTCP_UP1":1202},{"wTCP_UP1":690},{"wTCP_UP1":3330},{"wTCP_UP1":1215},{"wTCP_UP1":2872},{"wTCP_UP1":1192},{"wTCP_UP1":474.1},{"wTCP_UP1":2855},{"wTCP_UP1":1185},{"wTCP_UP1":1184},{"wTCP_UP1":1214},{"wTCP_UP1":727},{"wTCP_UP1":1902.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1190},{"wTCP_UP1":1639.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1286},{"wTCP_UP1":1182},{"wTCP_UP1":800},{"wTCP_UP1":1191},{"wTCP_UP1":290.1},{"wTCP_UP1":1155},{"wTCP_UP1":1209},{"wTCP_UP1":857},{"wTCP_UP1":376.4},{"wTCP_UP1":1033},{"wTCP_UP1":589},{"wTCP_UP1":394},{"wTCP_UP1":1441},{"wTCP_UP1":1723},{"wTCP_UP1":1204},{"wTCP_UP1":1212},{"wTCP_UP1":1659},{"wTCP_UP1":731},{"wTCP_UP1":568},{"wTCP_UP1":1163},{"wTCP_UP1":588},{"wTCP_UP1":0},{"wTCP_UP1":1469},{"wTCP_UP1":807.9},{"wTCP_UP1":1222},{"wTCP_UP1":773},{"wTCP_UP1":1181},{"wTCP_UP1":1169},{"wTCP_UP1":1106},{"wTCP_UP1":553},{"wTCP_UP1":392.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1022},{"wTCP_UP1":792},{"wTCP_UP1":1036},{"wTCP_UP1":1250},{"wTCP_UP1":711.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1162},{"wTCP_UP1":1074},{"wTCP_UP1":419},{"wTCP_UP1":806},{"wTCP_UP1":428},{"wTCP_UP1":957},{"wTCP_UP1":1150},{"wTCP_UP1":987},{"wTCP_UP1":846},{"wTCP_UP1":998},{"wTCP_UP1":705},{"wTCP_UP1":221.8},{"wTCP_UP1":1097},{"wTCP_UP1":344},{"wTCP_UP1":856},{"wTCP_UP1":383.1},{"wTCP_UP1":171.9},{"wTCP_UP1":446.9},{"wTCP_UP1":3147},{"wTCP_UP1":719},{"wTCP_UP1":1119},{"wTCP_UP1":441.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1740},{"wTCP_UP1":1027},{"wTCP_UP1":53.8},{"wTCP_UP1":1072},{"wTCP_UP1":1193},{"wTCP_UP1":1079},{"wTCP_UP1":1092},{"wTCP_UP1":155.8},{"wTCP_UP1":576},{"wTCP_UP1":1243},{"wTCP_UP1":335.6},{"wTCP_UP1":213},{"wTCP_UP1":180.3},{"wTCP_UP1":256.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1137},{"wTCP_UP1":465},{"wTCP_UP1":223.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1536},{"wTCP_UP1":701},{"wTCP_UP1":622},{"wTCP_UP1":815},{"wTCP_UP1":261},{"wTCP_UP1":31.2},{"wTCP_UP1":597},{"wTCP_UP1":301.4},{"wTCP_UP1":643},{"wTCP_UP1":1133},{"wTCP_UP1":462.2},{"wTCP_UP1":488.7},{"wTCP_UP1":438.7},{"wTCP_UP1":281},{"wTCP_UP1":432.9},{"wTCP_UP1":59.6},{"wTCP_UP1":191},{"wTCP_UP1":479},{"wTCP_UP1":85.8},{"wTCP_UP1":170.3},{"wTCP_UP1":380.7},{"wTCP_UP1":248.7},{"wTCP_UP1":251.3},{"wTCP_UP1":102.4},{"wTCP_UP1":276.8},{"wTCP_UP1":648},{"wTCP_UP1":661},{"wTCP_UP1":341.5},{"wTCP_UP1":240.7},{"wTCP_UP1":511},{"wTCP_UP1":148.1},{"wTCP_UP1":305.4},{"wTCP_UP1":86.4},{"wTCP_UP1":1564.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1276},{"wTCP_UP1":944.55},{"wTCP_UP1":1437.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1510.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1483},{"wTCP_UP1":1031.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1535},{"wTCP_UP1":1317.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1501},{"wTCP_UP1":1614},{"wTCP_UP1":1229},{"wTCP_UP1":1444},{"wTCP_UP1":1196},{"wTCP_UP1":1369.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1166},{"wTCP_UP1":100.7},{"wTCP_UP1":662.6},{"wTCP_UP1":945},{"wTCP_UP1":1135},{"wTCP_UP1":490.2},{"wTCP_UP1":961},{"wTCP_UP1":1042.5},{"wTCP_UP1":400.55},{"wTCP_UP1":935},{"wTCP_UP1":562.05},{"wTCP_UP1":966.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1132},{"wTCP_UP1":674.45},{"wTCP_UP1":755.5},{"wTCP_UP1":946},{"wTCP_UP1":821},{"wTCP_UP1":536.3},{"wTCP_UP1":512.5},{"wTCP_UP1":775.8},{"wTCP_UP1":1026},{"wTCP_UP1":937.5},{"wTCP_UP1":920},{"wTCP_UP1":1015},{"wTCP_UP1":1020},{"wTCP_UP1":433.2},{"wTCP_UP1":1021},{"wTCP_UP1":1211},{"wTCP_UP1":277.1},{"wTCP_UP1":439.85},{"wTCP_UP1":924},{"wTCP_UP1":629},{"wTCP_UP1":912},{"wTCP_UP1":514.35},{"wTCP_UP1":494.45},{"wTCP_UP1":688},{"wTCP_UP1":265.5},{"wTCP_UP1":910},{"wTCP_UP1":809},{"wTCP_UP1":749.35},{"wTCP_UP1":934},{"wTCP_UP1":906},{"wTCP_UP1":917},{"wTCP_UP1":1065},{"wTCP_UP1":762},{"wTCP_UP1":231.8},{"wTCP_UP1":860},{"wTCP_UP1":859},{"wTCP_UP1":997},{"wTCP_UP1":614},{"wTCP_UP1":779.5},{"wTCP_UP1":935.5},{"wTCP_UP1":876.8},{"wTCP_UP1":481.7},{"wTCP_UP1":355.2},{"wTCP_UP1":796},{"wTCP_UP1":343.7},{"wTCP_UP1":793},{"wTCP_UP1":903},{"wTCP_UP1":706},{"wTCP_UP1":854},{"wTCP_UP1":287.6},{"wTCP_UP1":652.7},{"wTCP_UP1":888},{"wTCP_UP1":362.9},{"wTCP_UP1":605},{"wTCP_UP1":874.5},{"wTCP_UP1":403.3},{"wTCP_UP1":868},{"wTCP_UP1":907},{"wTCP_UP1":689},{"wTCP_UP1":712.9},{"wTCP_UP1":428.7},{"wTCP_UP1":94.6},{"wTCP_UP1":676},{"wTCP_UP1":476.5},{"wTCP_UP1":280.15},{"wTCP_UP1":409.05},{"wTCP_UP1":745.5},{"wTCP_UP1":108},{"wTCP_UP1":609},{"wTCP_UP1":776.7},{"wTCP_UP1":941},{"wTCP_UP1":746},{"wTCP_UP1":224.4},{"wTCP_UP1":767},{"wTCP_UP1":582},{"wTCP_UP1":664},{"wTCP_UP1":633},{"wTCP_UP1":520.9},{"wTCP_UP1":715},{"wTCP_UP1":779},{"wTCP_UP1":507.8},{"wTCP_UP1":696},{"wTCP_UP1":255.3},{"wTCP_UP1":477},{"wTCP_UP1":675.5},{"wTCP_UP1":695},{"wTCP_UP1":755},{"wTCP_UP1":670.5},{"wTCP_UP1":512.55},{"wTCP_UP1":447.3},{"wTCP_UP1":551},{"wTCP_UP1":406.6},{"wTCP_UP1":643.7},{"wTCP_UP1":735.8},{"wTCP_UP1":188.9},{"wTCP_UP1":189.8},{"wTCP_UP1":199.7},{"wTCP_UP1":264.5},{"wTCP_UP1":221.1},{"wTCP_UP1":556.15},{"wTCP_UP1":491.1},{"wTCP_UP1":349.2},{"wTCP_UP1":448},{"wTCP_UP1":891},{"wTCP_UP1":224.8},{"wTCP_UP1":714},{"wTCP_UP1":850},{"wTCP_UP1":602},{"wTCP_UP1":206.9},{"wTCP_UP1":226.9},{"wTCP_UP1":424.1},{"wTCP_UP1":1005},{"wTCP_UP1":944},{"wTCP_UP1":247.7},{"wTCP_UP1":99.6},{"wTCP_UP1":93.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2266.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2348},{"wTCP_UP1":2849},{"wTCP_UP1":3093},{"wTCP_UP1":2816},{"wTCP_UP1":1156},{"wTCP_UP1":2015},{"wTCP_UP1":1351},{"wTCP_UP1":3193},{"wTCP_UP1":3066},{"wTCP_UP1":1297.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1417},{"wTCP_UP1":2940},{"wTCP_UP1":2674},{"wTCP_UP1":1542},{"wTCP_UP1":2166},{"wTCP_UP1":526.3},{"wTCP_UP1":3559},{"wTCP_UP1":2587},{"wTCP_UP1":994.5},{"wTCP_UP1":865},{"wTCP_UP1":1613},{"wTCP_UP1":1635.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1465},{"wTCP_UP1":1681},{"wTCP_UP1":2146},{"wTCP_UP1":2908},{"wTCP_UP1":604.35},{"wTCP_UP1":2404},{"wTCP_UP1":1751.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1407.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1008.45},{"wTCP_UP1":2148},{"wTCP_UP1":500.3},{"wTCP_UP1":918},{"wTCP_UP1":1738.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1116.95},{"wTCP_UP1":1608.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1153.5},{"wTCP_UP1":543.85},{"wTCP_UP1":369.6},{"wTCP_UP1":2102},{"wTCP_UP1":1520.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1149.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1797.5},{"wTCP_UP1":308.6},{"wTCP_UP1":1366},{"wTCP_UP1":168},{"wTCP_UP1":1647},{"wTCP_UP1":407.4},{"wTCP_UP1":1056},{"wTCP_UP1":779.6},{"wTCP_UP1":2571.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1568},{"wTCP_UP1":1385},{"wTCP_UP1":1645},{"wTCP_UP1":2710},{"wTCP_UP1":2556},{"wTCP_UP1":1034},{"wTCP_UP1":1571},{"wTCP_UP1":239.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1362},{"wTCP_UP1":2207},{"wTCP_UP1":816},{"wTCP_UP1":962},{"wTCP_UP1":1057},{"wTCP_UP1":869},{"wTCP_UP1":444.45},{"wTCP_UP1":579.85},{"wTCP_UP1":328.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1705},{"wTCP_UP1":2740},{"wTCP_UP1":537.2},{"wTCP_UP1":1085},{"wTCP_UP1":1796},{"wTCP_UP1":930},{"wTCP_UP1":702.25},{"wTCP_UP1":628},{"wTCP_UP1":447.45},{"wTCP_UP1":1182.4},{"wTCP_UP1":620.1},{"wTCP_UP1":99.45},{"wTCP_UP1":232.65},{"wTCP_UP1":77.1},{"wTCP_UP1":1091.75},{"wTCP_UP1":349.5},{"wTCP_UP1":545},{"wTCP_UP1":3373},{"wTCP_UP1":739.3},{"wTCP_UP1":2993},{"wTCP_UP1":1505},{"wTCP_UP1":879},{"wTCP_UP1":913},{"wTCP_UP1":490.3},{"wTCP_UP1":852.5},{"wTCP_UP1":621},{"wTCP_UP1":1059},{"wTCP_UP1":618},{"wTCP_UP1":499.2},{"wTCP_UP1":1274},{"wTCP_UP1":784.85},{"wTCP_UP1":597.8},{"wTCP_UP1":48.6},{"wTCP_UP1":831},{"wTCP_UP1":841.6},{"wTCP_UP1":686.8},{"wTCP_UP1":1262},{"wTCP_UP1":674.85},{"wTCP_UP1":663},{"wTCP_UP1":265.7},{"wTCP_UP1":87.8},{"wTCP_UP1":670},{"wTCP_UP1":581.9},{"wTCP_UP1":216.5},{"wTCP_UP1":435.9},{"wTCP_UP1":791},{"wTCP_UP1":468.7},{"wTCP_UP1":761},{"wTCP_UP1":1268},{"wTCP_UP1":828.1},{"wTCP_UP1":870},{"wTCP_UP1":452.8},{"wTCP_UP1":359},{"wTCP_UP1":515.8},{"wTCP_UP1":580},{"wTCP_UP1":377.2},{"wTCP_UP1":176.55},{"wTCP_UP1":386.4},{"wTCP_UP1":209.2},{"wTCP_UP1":127.7},{"wTCP_UP1":193.3},{"wTCP_UP1":197.6},{"wTCP_UP1":201.3},{"wTCP_UP1":202.8},{"wTCP_UP1":57.7},{"wTCP_UP1":89.6},{"wTCP_UP1":285.3},{"wTCP_UP1":46.4},{"wTCP_UP1":399.7},{"wTCP_UP1":294},{"wTCP_UP1":80.8},{"wTCP_UP1":47.3},{"wTCP_UP1":15399},{"wTCP_UP1":16822},{"wTCP_UP1":15586},{"wTCP_UP1":4160},{"wTCP_UP1":16331},{"wTCP_UP1":15302},{"wTCP_UP1":12720},{"wTCP_UP1":9028},{"wTCP_UP1":11518},{"wTCP_UP1":13374},{"wTCP_UP1":13731.5},{"wTCP_UP1":15747},{"wTCP_UP1":10853},{"wTCP_UP1":13441.5},{"wTCP_UP1":17134},{"wTCP_UP1":7740},{"wTCP_UP1":7868},{"wTCP_UP1":11822},{"wTCP_UP1":14247},{"wTCP_UP1":7401.5},{"wTCP_UP1":10959},{"wTCP_UP1":8949},{"wTCP_UP1":6431},{"wTCP_UP1":15467},{"wTCP_UP1":15657},{"wTCP_UP1":6426},{"wTCP_UP1":9955.5},{"wTCP_UP1":11720.5},{"wTCP_UP1":3828.5},{"wTCP_UP1":4332},{"wTCP_UP1":5894},{"wTCP_UP1":15749},{"wTCP_UP1":12015},{"wTCP_UP1":7594},{"wTCP_UP1":2609},{"wTCP_UP1":8483.5},{"wTCP_UP1":5726},{"wTCP_UP1":8324},{"wTCP_UP1":6533},{"wTCP_UP1":3841.5},{"wTCP_UP1":9783},{"wTCP_UP1":3099.9},{"wTCP_UP1":8439.5},{"wTCP_UP1":8969},{"wTCP_UP1":8962.5},{"wTCP_UP1":10479},{"wTCP_UP1":8978},{"wTCP_UP1":10879.5},{"wTCP_UP1":6090.5},{"wTCP_UP1":6841},{"wTCP_UP1":5438},{"wTCP_UP1":8964.5},{"wTCP_UP1":9731},{"wTCP_UP1":3400.65},{"wTCP_UP1":6335},{"wTCP_UP1":5151},{"wTCP_UP1":7644.5},{"wTCP_UP1":12392},{"wTCP_UP1":2213.3},{"wTCP_UP1":15823},{"wTCP_UP1":6875},{"wTCP_UP1":1999},{"wTCP_UP1":3331.7},{"wTCP_UP1":3427.2},{"wTCP_UP1":4779.05},{"wTCP_UP1":3413.3},{"wTCP_UP1":8898},{"wTCP_UP1":12797},{"wTCP_UP1":9509},{"wTCP_UP1":5323},{"wTCP_UP1":3565.9},{"wTCP_UP1":3521.5},{"wTCP_UP1":4689},{"wTCP_UP1":2841.5},{"wTCP_UP1":847},{"wTCP_UP1":260.2},{"wTCP_UP1":3424},{"wTCP_UP1":3570.5},{"wTCP_UP1":350},{"wTCP_UP1":2107.2},{"wTCP_UP1":3414.6},{"wTCP_UP1":2094},{"wTCP_UP1":4198.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2394.4},{"wTCP_UP1":3630},{"wTCP_UP1":1055.5},{"wTCP_UP1":3263},{"wTCP_UP1":1009.8},{"wTCP_UP1":964.2},{"wTCP_UP1":911.8},{"wTCP_UP1":822.95},{"wTCP_UP1":976},{"wTCP_UP1":733.9},{"wTCP_UP1":955},{"wTCP_UP1":1221.65},{"wTCP_UP1":995},{"wTCP_UP1":984},{"wTCP_UP1":916},{"wTCP_UP1":975.3},{"wTCP_UP1":28},{"wTCP_UP1":983},{"wTCP_UP1":611},{"wTCP_UP1":973},{"wTCP_UP1":926},{"wTCP_UP1":518},{"wTCP_UP1":977},{"wTCP_UP1":969},{"wTCP_UP1":921},{"wTCP_UP1":950},{"wTCP_UP1":758},{"wTCP_UP1":931},{"wTCP_UP1":935.9},{"wTCP_UP1":281.2},{"wTCP_UP1":973.8},{"wTCP_UP1":823},{"wTCP_UP1":190.9},{"wTCP_UP1":395},{"wTCP_UP1":890.4},{"wTCP_UP1":370.5},{"wTCP_UP1":258.6},{"wTCP_UP1":297.25},{"wTCP_UP1":530.2},{"wTCP_UP1":313.5},{"wTCP_UP1":902},{"wTCP_UP1":1007.8},{"wTCP_UP1":611.1},{"wTCP_UP1":183.2},{"wTCP_UP1":785.5},{"wTCP_UP1":667.5},{"wTCP_UP1":811},{"wTCP_UP1":963},{"wTCP_UP1":448.4},{"wTCP_UP1":177.4},{"wTCP_UP1":312.3},{"wTCP_UP1":136},{"wTCP_UP1":421.4},{"wTCP_UP1":752},{"wTCP_UP1":487.1},{"wTCP_UP1":96.5},{"wTCP_UP1":274.8},{"wTCP_UP1":2836},{"wTCP_UP1":1812},{"wTCP_UP1":949},{"wTCP_UP1":615},{"wTCP_UP1":184.3},{"wTCP_UP1":1648},{"wTCP_UP1":1213},{"wTCP_UP1":1230},{"wTCP_UP1":1043},{"wTCP_UP1":1124},{"wTCP_UP1":87.3},{"wTCP_UP1":576.8},{"wTCP_UP1":587},{"wTCP_UP1":1174},{"wTCP_UP1":747},{"wTCP_UP1":71.3},{"wTCP_UP1":1167},{"wTCP_UP1":1028},{"wTCP_UP1":1183},{"wTCP_UP1":479.3},{"wTCP_UP1":981},{"wTCP_UP1":1165},{"wTCP_UP1":1016},{"wTCP_UP1":1090},{"wTCP_UP1":864},{"wTCP_UP1":1348},{"wTCP_UP1":487.9},{"wTCP_UP1":181.6},{"wTCP_UP1":776},{"wTCP_UP1":716.7},{"wTCP_UP1":722},{"wTCP_UP1":481.5},{"wTCP_UP1":176},{"wTCP_UP1":323.4},{"wTCP_UP1":231.9},{"wTCP_UP1":1141},{"wTCP_UP1":389.1},{"wTCP_UP1":799},{"wTCP_UP1":1127},{"wTCP_UP1":460},{"wTCP_UP1":134.6},{"wTCP_UP1":592},{"wTCP_UP1":469.7},{"wTCP_UP1":431.1},{"wTCP_UP1":295},{"wTCP_UP1":196.5},{"wTCP_UP1":560},{"wTCP_UP1":154.9},{"wTCP_UP1":145.2},{"wTCP_UP1":254.6},{"wTCP_UP1":873},{"wTCP_UP1":400.1},{"wTCP_UP1":1023},{"wTCP_UP1":709},{"wTCP_UP1":408.3},{"wTCP_UP1":634.4},{"wTCP_UP1":596},{"wTCP_UP1":1294},{"wTCP_UP1":897},{"wTCP_UP1":613},{"wTCP_UP1":341.1},{"wTCP_UP1":391.6},{"wTCP_UP1":958},{"wTCP_UP1":680},{"wTCP_UP1":898},{"wTCP_UP1":544.6},{"wTCP_UP1":163.6},{"wTCP_UP1":521.6},{"wTCP_UP1":180.4},{"wTCP_UP1":396.8},{"wTCP_UP1":750},{"wTCP_UP1":172.6},{"wTCP_UP1":376.3},{"wTCP_UP1":798},{"wTCP_UP1":294.6},{"wTCP_UP1":373.1},{"wTCP_UP1":642.8},{"wTCP_UP1":110.4},{"wTCP_UP1":449.8},{"wTCP_UP1":443.7},{"wTCP_UP1":726},{"wTCP_UP1":454.6},{"wTCP_UP1":507.7},{"wTCP_UP1":157.1},{"wTCP_UP1":57.2},{"wTCP_UP1":2313},{"wTCP_UP1":2384},{"wTCP_UP1":858},{"wTCP_UP1":3053},{"wTCP_UP1":1436},{"wTCP_UP1":1311},{"wTCP_UP1":936},{"wTCP_UP1":251.4},{"wTCP_UP1":261.3},{"wTCP_UP1":1394},{"wTCP_UP1":808},{"wTCP_UP1":704},{"wTCP_UP1":653.9},{"wTCP_UP1":836},{"wTCP_UP1":678},{"wTCP_UP1":600.2},{"wTCP_UP1":612},{"wTCP_UP1":569.5},{"wTCP_UP1":600.6},{"wTCP_UP1":517.4},{"wTCP_UP1":208.8},{"wTCP_UP1":208.6},{"wTCP_UP1":202.2},{"wTCP_UP1":178.1},{"wTCP_UP1":179.2},{"wTCP_UP1":125.6},{"wTCP_UP1":192.8},{"wTCP_UP1":68.2},{"wTCP_UP1":154.8},{"wTCP_UP1":247.1},{"wTCP_UP1":95.6},{"wTCP_UP1":93.7},{"wTCP_UP1":960},{"wTCP_UP1":1039},{"wTCP_UP1":918.9},{"wTCP_UP1":966},{"wTCP_UP1":1001},{"wTCP_UP1":384.9},{"wTCP_UP1":732},{"wTCP_UP1":915.1},{"wTCP_UP1":1030},{"wTCP_UP1":877},{"wTCP_UP1":989},{"wTCP_UP1":29.6},{"wTCP_UP1":1018},{"wTCP_UP1":246.7},{"wTCP_UP1":360.9},{"wTCP_UP1":928},{"wTCP_UP1":477.7},{"wTCP_UP1":1024},{"wTCP_UP1":972},{"wTCP_UP1":875},{"wTCP_UP1":830},{"wTCP_UP1":1042},{"wTCP_UP1":354.5},{"wTCP_UP1":612.9},{"wTCP_UP1":209.1},{"wTCP_UP1":668},{"wTCP_UP1":175.7},{"wTCP_UP1":133.2},{"wTCP_UP1":199},{"wTCP_UP1":279.4},{"wTCP_UP1":247.3},{"wTCP_UP1":722.9},{"wTCP_UP1":231.3},{"wTCP_UP1":699},{"wTCP_UP1":1014.7},{"wTCP_UP1":896.1},{"wTCP_UP1":348.5},{"wTCP_UP1":169.7},{"wTCP_UP1":49.7},{"wTCP_UP1":16298},{"wTCP_UP1":18324},{"wTCP_UP1":16526},{"wTCP_UP1":18320},{"wTCP_UP1":14401},{"wTCP_UP1":16179},{"wTCP_UP1":14740},{"wTCP_UP1":17530},{"wTCP_UP1":16955},{"wTCP_UP1":16545},{"wTCP_UP1":14592},{"wTCP_UP1":10274},{"wTCP_UP1":1142},{"wTCP_UP1":1343},{"wTCP_UP1":1130},{"wTCP_UP1":1197},{"wTCP_UP1":11128},{"wTCP_UP1":1160},{"wTCP_UP1":11638},{"wTCP_UP1":5477},{"wTCP_UP1":1178},{"wTCP_UP1":8858},{"wTCP_UP1":1277.8},{"wTCP_UP1":9904},{"wTCP_UP1":894},{"wTCP_UP1":6073},{"wTCP_UP1":5336},{"wTCP_UP1":9712},{"wTCP_UP1":449.2},{"wTCP_UP1":1093},{"wTCP_UP1":1009},{"wTCP_UP1":1218},{"wTCP_UP1":1206},{"wTCP_UP1":5276},{"wTCP_UP1":1174.5},{"wTCP_UP1":737.6},{"wTCP_UP1":724},{"wTCP_UP1":1283.1},{"wTCP_UP1":903.4},{"wTCP_UP1":4494},{"wTCP_UP1":1203},{"wTCP_UP1":1349},{"wTCP_UP1":975},{"wTCP_UP1":204.4},{"wTCP_UP1":656},{"wTCP_UP1":647.9},{"wTCP_UP1":161.4},{"wTCP_UP1":1115.6},{"wTCP_UP1":531.1},{"wTCP_UP1":364.8},{"wTCP_UP1":1007.7},{"wTCP_UP1":849},{"wTCP_UP1":662},{"wTCP_UP1":1175},{"wTCP_UP1":31.5},{"wTCP_UP1":561.4},{"wTCP_UP1":1025},{"wTCP_UP1":469},{"wTCP_UP1":1525},{"wTCP_UP1":1089},{"wTCP_UP1":1024.65},{"wTCP_UP1":683},{"wTCP_UP1":1017},{"wTCP_UP1":1245},{"wTCP_UP1":1091},{"wTCP_UP1":1060},{"wTCP_UP1":1244},{"wTCP_UP1":933},{"wTCP_UP1":959},{"wTCP_UP1":904.5},{"wTCP_UP1":888.5},{"wTCP_UP1":438.2},{"wTCP_UP1":844.5},{"wTCP_UP1":726.6},{"wTCP_UP1":589.4},{"wTCP_UP1":709.95},{"wTCP_UP1":737.5},{"wTCP_UP1":834.7},{"wTCP_UP1":829.4},{"wTCP_UP1":711},{"wTCP_UP1":915},{"wTCP_UP1":671.8},{"wTCP_UP1":711.5},{"wTCP_UP1":701.65},{"wTCP_UP1":754},{"wTCP_UP1":809.5},{"wTCP_UP1":536.5},{"wTCP_UP1":499.1},{"wTCP_UP1":632.4},{"wTCP_UP1":584.35},{"wTCP_UP1":351.6},{"wTCP_UP1":567},{"wTCP_UP1":610.7},{"wTCP_UP1":837},{"wTCP_UP1":468.65},{"wTCP_UP1":772.35},{"wTCP_UP1":465.6},{"wTCP_UP1":781.5},{"wTCP_UP1":361.2},{"wTCP_UP1":204},{"wTCP_UP1":817.5},{"wTCP_UP1":517.75},{"wTCP_UP1":515.35},{"wTCP_UP1":436},{"wTCP_UP1":446.7},{"wTCP_UP1":167.6},{"wTCP_UP1":616},{"wTCP_UP1":134.9},{"wTCP_UP1":285.5},{"wTCP_UP1":240.8},{"wTCP_UP1":482.1},{"wTCP_UP1":384.3},{"wTCP_UP1":3435},{"wTCP_UP1":2395.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2950},{"wTCP_UP1":2504.5},{"wTCP_UP1":3553.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2168.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2048.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1885.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2363.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2471.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1091.6},{"wTCP_UP1":1166.45},{"wTCP_UP1":883.9},{"wTCP_UP1":1760},{"wTCP_UP1":2480},{"wTCP_UP1":1246},{"wTCP_UP1":2766},{"wTCP_UP1":1894.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2727.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1791},{"wTCP_UP1":1663.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1994.5},{"wTCP_UP1":1232.2},{"wTCP_UP1":235.2},{"wTCP_UP1":1193.5},{"wTCP_UP1":434.2},{"wTCP_UP1":2265.5},{"wTCP_UP1":819.9},{"wTCP_UP1":637.25},{"wTCP_UP1":1052},{"wTCP_UP1":416},{"wTCP_UP1":1799},{"wTCP_UP1":409.6},{"wTCP_UP1":337.1},{"wTCP_UP1":553.95},{"wTCP_UP1":1116.4},{"wTCP_UP1":663.55},{"wTCP_UP1":577.5},{"wTCP_UP1":969.75},{"wTCP_UP1":348.55},{"wTCP_UP1":791.45},{"wTCP_UP1":217.3},{"wTCP_UP1":602.5},{"wTCP_UP1":521.7},{"wTCP_UP1":124},{"wTCP_UP1":145.5},{"wTCP_UP1":729.55},{"wTCP_UP1":654.9},{"wTCP_UP1":346.75},{"wTCP_UP1":569.4},{"wTCP_UP1":662.35},{"wTCP_UP1":334.05},{"wTCP_UP1":187},{"wTCP_UP1":151.25},{"wTCP_UP1":224.1},{"wTCP_UP1":223},{"wTCP_UP1":224.6},{"wTCP_UP1":139.1},{"wTCP_UP1":69.2},{"wTCP_UP1":58.6},{"wTCP_UP1":117.5},{"wTCP_UP1":15584.5},{"wTCP_UP1":15434},{"wTCP_UP1":15971.5},{"wTCP_UP1":10702},{"wTCP_UP1":16623},{"wTCP_UP1":15538},{"wTCP_UP1":7471},{"wTCP_UP1":15334},{"wTCP_UP1":9314.9},{"wTCP_UP1":11608.5},{"wTCP_UP1":8625},{"wTCP_UP1":9771},{"wTCP_UP1":10982},{"wTCP_UP1":8666.5},{"wTCP_UP1":5658.25},{"wTCP_UP1":4989},{"wTCP_UP1":4636.45},{"wTCP_UP1":8519.5},{"wTCP_UP1":9169.6},{"wTCP_UP1":9831.65},{"wTCP_UP1":10984},{"wTCP_UP1":6348.5},{"wTCP_UP1":5604.05},{"wTCP_UP1":2996},{"wTCP_UP1":570.85},{"wTCP_UP1":8218.15},{"wTCP_UP1":2249},{"wTCP_UP1":10827},{"wTCP_UP1":8318.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2431.85},{"wTCP_UP1":5164.65},{"wTCP_UP1":4627},{"wTCP_UP1":1197.85},{"wTCP_UP1":10832.5},{"wTCP_UP1":3777.5},{"wTCP_UP1":5365.5},{"wTCP_UP1":2588},{"wTCP_UP1":768.1},{"wTCP_UP1":4481},{"wTCP_UP1":3612},{"wTCP_UP1":3069},{"wTCP_UP1":5843},{"wTCP_UP1":2269.9},{"wTCP_UP1":679.3},{"wTCP_UP1":3559.5},{"wTCP_UP1":4442},{"wTCP_UP1":3708.9},{"wTCP_UP1":1035},{"wTCP_UP1":503.1},{"wTCP_UP1":525},{"wTCP_UP1":491.35},{"wTCP_UP1":593.55},{"wTCP_UP1":845.85},{"wTCP_UP1":373.7},{"wTCP_UP1":663.1},{"wTCP_UP1":803},{"wTCP_UP1":482},{"wTCP_UP1":516},{"wTCP_UP1":1412},{"wTCP_UP1":659.3}]
```

Comment: What does your file structure look like? I don't see where you are loading your HTML file from the PHP file. Also, in your PHP, why are you `echo`'ing the data? Where does that data show up? If you are `echo`'ing the `json_encode`'ed data, there is no need to `new Array(` around the data.

Comment: can you post the output json data from this line? `echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` i think the problem is in the json data.

Comment: Just added the Json data on the bottom

Comment: In the JSON you need to use the y value, instead of custom field name like "wTCP_UP1"

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with highcharts before, but here are a couple changes that might get you closer.

First, when you're just messing around trying to get stuff to work, it's easier (at least for me) to just put everything in one file.

Second, *I think* you need jQuery. So I added that script to the top. Also, when working with jQuery, you should put your scripts after the elements they are referencing, and better yet, put your function calls in a `$(document).ready(function() { // do code here });` call. This will ensure you elements are loaded to the DOM before anything tries to find them.

Third, if you are `json_encode`'ing your PHP data, you can just assign that directly to the javascript variable, no need to do `new Array()`.

Give this a try, let me know if any errors occur:

```
<?php
// A simple PHP script demonstrating how to connect to MySQL.
// Press the 'Run' button on the top to start the web server,
// then click the URL that is emitted to the Output tab of the console.
$servername = getenv('IP');
$username   = getenv('C9_USER');
$password   = "";
$database   = "reports2";
$dbport     = 3306;
// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);
// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$query  = "SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_la UNION ALL SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_rs UNION SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_sf";        
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$data   = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row; 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Area Example</title>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                   chart: {
                    type: 'area'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                        'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    labels: {

                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>  <br/>warheads in {point.x}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        pointStart: 1940,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 2,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: js_array
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No luck with this code. I get a connection error now.

Comment: You will need to make sure your connection information is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Highchart uses custom formatted json. Specifically for your case, you can try this :

```
<?php

$servername = getenv('IP');
$username = getenv('C9_USER');
$password = "";
$database = "reports2";
$dbport = 3306;

$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully (".$db->host_info.")";
$query = "SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_la UNION ALL SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_rs UNION           SELECT wTCP_UP1 FROM 1_sp12_sf";        
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $data[] = $row; 
}
        $json_data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        $data2 = str_replace('{"wTCP_UP1":', '', $json_data);
        $data3 = str_replace('}', '', $data2);



    ?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Area Example</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">   </div>

    <script type = "text/javascript">  

     $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Uptime',
                data: <?php echo $data3;?>
            }]
        });
    });
     </script>
      </head>
      <body>
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0    auto"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The last 2 `str_replace` function just removes `{"wTCP_UP1":` and `}` from the resulting json to have a format like this:

```
[6163,13622,456.1,2142.3,6317,1710,............659.3]
```

You can make this comma seperated string in your while loop without encoding it to json and removing unwanted characters.

With your sample json output, my result looks like this:
[image: Highchart Sample]

Comment: hey `alex12555`  if this works, you can mark this answer as selected. if it has any problem, let me know. thanks in advance.